# Find all irreducible monic polynomials of degrees $2$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{4}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Premise: not a native speaker.

So: I really don't know how to find all the polynomials except to calculate them all:

\begin{equation}x^{2}+ax+b \end{equation} \begin{equation} a,b ∈ {(0, 1, 2, 3)} \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
1)x^{2}\\
2)x^{2} + x\\
3)x^{2} + 1\\
4)x^{2} + x + 1\\
5)x^{2} + 2x\\
6)x^{2} + 2\\
7)x^{2} + 2x + 1\\
8)x^{2} + x + 2\\
9)x^{2} + 2x + 2\\
10)x^{2} + 3x\\
11)x^{2} + 3\\
12)x^{2} + 3x + 3\\
13)x^{2} + 3x + 1\\
14)x^{2} + 32 + 2\\
15)x^{2} + x + 3\\
16)x^{2} + 2x +3\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I know that only numbers 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 13, 15, 16 are Irreducible, because they didn't have roots in $\Bbb{Z}_{4}[x]$.

My question is: is there a more orthodox method to find the irreducible polynomials? Because with larger numbers, this method is not that practical.

Comment: $15$ isn't irreducible.  $(x+3)(x+2)=x^2+5x+6=x^2+x+2.$

Comment: Irreducibility over rings with zero divisors is complicated. For instance, $ (2x+1)(2x+2)=2x+2$. Is $2x+2$ reducible? Or $ (2x+1)(2x+3) =3$. Is $3$ reducible?

Comment: Don’t worry about your command of English. You did better than most.

Comment: 15 should have been $x^{2}+x+3$, my mistake.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}_4$? The mod 4 ring or the field with 4 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to count all reducible monic polynomials of degree $2$ because they are just the product of two monic linear polynomials, which are $x,x-1,x-2,x-3$ in your cases. So there are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ products of different linear polynomials. As Robert pointed out, there are also $2$ squares of them. There are $16$ possible monic polynomials in $\Bbb{Z}_{4}[x]$ so there are $8$ irreducible such polynomials. In general, I think this is the efficient way to find all reducible and thus, all irreducible monic polynomials. For polynomials with larger degree, we can start with those with smaller degree first. For example, to know all reducible monic polynomials of degree $3$, we need to know irreducible linear polynomials and for degree $4$, we need to know all irreducible polynomials of degree $1$ and $2$.

Comment: For degree $3$, it's enough to know the irreducible monic polynomials of degree $1$.  If a monic cubic polynomial factors, one of its factors has to be linear.  Also, you forgot to account for the squares of monic polynomials (two of which are equal to each other), so there are actually $9$ reducible monic polynomials of degree $2$ in $\Bbb Z_4[x]$.

Comment: Thank you Robert for pointing my mistake on counting reducible polynomials. So there are 8 irreducible ones right? For the other comment, I meant for degree 3 and 4, we need to know about degree 1 and 2. I will edit my answer to make it clear.

Comment: There are $7$ irreducible monic polynomials of degree $2$ over $\Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks to both.. but now I'm lost. There are 7 or 8 irreducible polynomials of degree 2 in $\Bbb{Z}_{4}[x]$? I counted 8 of them, but the solution of the exercise, actually, counted 7 of them. More specific: why $x^{2}+2x+3$ isn't irreducible?

Comment: @Gello  That one is irreducible, but when I wrote my comment, 15 was a different polynomial.  The question was edited after I wrote my comment.  But I forgot to realize that $(x+2)^2=x^2$ so there are $8$ reducible polynomials, not $9$ as stated in my earlier comment.

Comment: Perfect: I tagged you because that polynomial is not reported in the solution, and it seemed odd. Thanks for the confirmation.